# Error: mysql57-community-release conflicts with mysql-community-release-el7-7.noarch

Tags: mysql, centos, centos7

When I try to install `mysql-community-release`, I get the following error:

```
# yum install mysql-community-release

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.uv.es
 * extras: mirror.uv.es
 * updates: mirror.uv.es
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-release.noarch 0:el7-7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch conflicts mysql-community-release
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mysql57-community-release conflicts with mysql-community-release-el7-7.noarch
```

This is the list of installed libraries:

```
# yum list installed mysql\*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.uv.es
 * extras: mirror.uv.es
 * updates: mirror.uv.es
Installed Packages
mysql-community-client.x86_64                         5.7.21-1.el7                 @mysql57-community
mysql-community-common.x86_64                         5.7.21-1.el7                 @mysql57-community
mysql-community-devel.x86_64                          5.7.21-1.el7                 @mysql57-community
mysql-community-embedded.x86_64                       5.7.21-1.el7                 @mysql57-community
mysql-community-embedded-compat.x86_64                5.7.21-1.el7                 @mysql57-community
mysql-community-embedded-devel.x86_64                 5.7.21-1.el7                 @mysql57-community
mysql-community-libs.x86_64                           5.7.21-1.el7                 @mysql57-community
mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64                    5.7.21-1.el7                 @mysql57-community
mysql-community-server.x86_64                         5.7.21-1.el7                 @mysql57-community
mysql-community-test.x86_64                           5.7.21-1.el7                 @mysql57-community
mysql57-community-release.noarch                      el7-11                       installed
```

How can I safely remove `mysql57-community-release`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check `#rpm -qa | grep mysql` to query list all rpm packages related to mysql

---

To remove mysql57-community-release issue:

`# rpm -e --nodeps mysql57-community-release`

Note: --no-deps no longer works, need to be --nodeps

Comment: Basically I need to install `mysql-community-release`. For some reason whenI run `yum install mysql-community-release` I get this message:
"Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.uv.es
 * extras: mirror.uv.es
 * updates: mirror.uv.es
No package mysql-community-release available.
Error: Nothing to do". How can I add repo?

Comment: @ScalaBoy the mysql-community yum repos can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/)

Comment: Here is the details on how to  mange repos , might be useful for you. 
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

Comment: @arjunJust an small typo or mismatch on your answer. The `--no-deps` option does not exists. The right one is `--nodeps` Your solution helped me out. Thanks!